# iOS Periodic Background Polling Rest API

Tags: ios, swift, polling, background-fetch

I want to create an iOS app where my app simply polls a public REST API every minute, in background, and give me local push notification if data from REST API matches my condition. Is this something that is possible and allowed by Apple?

Comment: Why don't you just save your "condition" in the server and make it notify you using push notifications that something changed? Or use a silent push notification to enable background downloading of new data? Unfortunately, the app cannot enable in the background by itself. Also note that this could lead to Apple review rejection, since fetching data every minute will make a huge impact in battery life.

Comment: well, i dont have a server, it's just polling from a public rest api, and i do not plan on publishing my app, just for personal use though..

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot execute in the background once every minute. Please check out Apple's documentation on background execution.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: im just making a simple app for my own self use, is this still not possible? im not publishing it to app store or anything

Comment: Anything is possible, it's just figuring out a way around Apple's security. I've seen apps use location updates or background audio to get background time. You just have to be creative.